# C# Is it possible to run a function with only a string?

Tags: c#, function, command

Sorry, this is kind of a stupid question.  So I’m making myself a personal assistant. I have an array of commands and for each one I have a function. If the user types in a command, how to I get it to go run the function?

Comment: Can you show some of your code? Are you using a dictionary? Have you heard of delegates?

Answer (score 2):

Let's define some commands as void methods with no return value.

```cs
private void DoCommand1() {
    Console.WriteLine("executing command 1");
}

private void DoCommand2() {
    Console.WriteLine("executing command 2");
}
```

You can use a Dictionary to map strings to functions:

```cs
var commands = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
commands.Add("command1", () => DoCommand1());
commands.Add("command2", () => DoCommand2());
```

and then run a command from a string:

```cs
string myCommand = "command2";
commands[myCommand].Invoke(); //will print "executing command 2"
```

You should have a look at [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) and [Action Delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.8) in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make some strongly type input and handle those input in C#. Here is how it can be done.

Make a Enum with all the command that you want to strongly type like Login, Logout for example.

Make a dictionary of

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, StronglyTypedCommands> localBotCommands = new Dictionary<string, StronglyTypedCommands>();
```

store some static string for what input you will get and what kind of command it is.

In the method you can figure out what exactly input is by help of this Dictionary.